# Why does a transaction under Snapshot Isolation Level take S and IX locks?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, snapshot, isolation-level

I'm investigating a deadlock and I see in deadlock xml file from profiler that process **process5332cf8** runs transaction under **Snapshot** isolation level (`isolationlevel="snapshot (5)"`).

But somehow it holds **IX** lock on a page and wants to take another one.

What can be the reason for this (except that isolation level was changed to non-snapshot in the middle of thansaction which is not likely to happen ) ?

Am I missing something about Snapshot IL ?

PS: the full xml: http://ideone.com/yuU9td

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writes always take locks. IX is a write lock. As for the other processes (the two SELECTs, process process6593498 and process5cc1498) they are under read committed.

If you want to avoid contention with snapshot isolation your must use it for your *read* transactions first of all.

Comment: Seems like I really missunderstood something about snapshot IL. Thank for your answer)

Comment: Kind of not related to this topic, but...could you advise me then, how do I force my sql-statements to run with snapshot if I don't explicitly begin a transaction?

Comment: Should I always explicitly start a transaction (even for a single statement?)? otherwise it will run under RC (default IL)

Comment: Yes, you must start a transaction. The alternative is to enable read_committed_snapshot on the database which will make every standalone read under read committed (default) use the so called 'read committed snapshot isolation' (RCSI). A good read is [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/).

Comment: yeah, thank you. I've already read that article recently. That's a nice one.